# Dynamic property assigned to object

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, http-caching, expandoobject

Is it possible to attach `dynamic` property to an object of user-defined class?

```
public class Room
{
    public int NumberOfDoors { get; set; }

    public int NumberOfWindows { get; set; }
}
```

then from other context:

```
Room room = new Room();

dynamic contact = new ExpandoObject();
contact.NumberOfWalls = 4;
```

and then *somehow* associate `NumberOfWalls` with `room`, as its property?

## Update (Larger Picture):

*as per @nawfal's suggestion*

I have a cached `List<Room>` being iterated in a razor view (outside the themes folder), calling a

particular partial view (from the current theme) for each element. One of the theme needs an extra

property in Room. I only have access to modify code in that particular theme folder, the partial

views cshtml files (don't ask why).

So its basically:

*(psuedocode)*

`Room.NoOfWalls = SomeHeavyLiftingProcess(Room.NoOfWindows, Room.NoOfDoors)`

I am looking for a way o update the `List<Room> rooms` object with NoOfWalls in

`HttpRuntime.Cache["rooms"]` to avoid calling `SomeHeavyLiftingProcess()` with each request. The

goal is to inject a property in cached object. Unfortuntely `HttpRuntime.Cache["rooms"]` is object

type and doesn't allow me to do this:

`HttpRuntime.Cache["rooms"][3]["NoOfWalls"] = SomeHeavyLiftingProcess(..)`

So I am thinking, for the first request (when cache is empty or invalid):

- Unpackig: Retrieve `(List<Room>)HttpRuntime.Cache["room"]`, inject NoOfWalls in the current room object.
- Repacking: Update `List<Room> room` with the new object and assign it back to `HttpRuntime.Cache`.

For the subsequent requests, the value of NoOfWalls will come from cached object `@Model.NoOfWalls`.

Comment: some online examples show that the `ExpandoObject` is used as a completely new kind of data with arbitrary members added by the programmer. That means you may not achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other way of achieving this JavaScript-like dynamic behavior in C#?

Comment: Why not just use `ExpandoObject`? You don't need the `Room` (or if needed, you can copy some properties from the ExpandoObject to the Room object), using ExpandoObject, you can add all the properties `NumberOfDoors`, `NumberOfWindows` and `NumberOfWalls`.

Comment: Can you tell us what the larger picture is? Like the use-case? There must be a couple of ways to do what you want to achieve eventually. You can associate it the other way, ie, a dynamic object with `Room` object's properties and values along with `NumberOfWalls` property.

Comment: @nawfal, please see the edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add properties not defined in a class to an existing instance, without using a dynamic object like `ExpandoObject`.

If you need to add members to an existing class, you can create a child class with a special constructor:

```
public class SpecialRoom : Room
{
    public SpecialRoom() { }

    public SpecialRoom(Room copy)
    {
        this.NumberOfDoors = copy.NumberOfDoors;
        this.NumberOfWindows = copy.NumberOfWindows;
    }

    public int NumberOfJacuzzis { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
var room = new Room();
room.NumberOfDoors = 3;

var specialRoom = new SpecialRoom(room)
{
    NumberOfJacuzzis = 7
};
```

Or:

```
var listOfRooms = new List<Room>();
// ...
var listOfSpecialRooms = listOfRooms.Select(x => new SpecialRoom(x));
listOfSpecialRooms.ForEach(x => x.NumberOfJacuzzis = ComplexCalculation(x));
```

If you have an existing concrete object (like an instance of the `Room` class), you can convert it to a dynamic object with a method like this:

```
public static dynamic ConvertObjectToDynamic(object value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    IDictionary<string, object> dynamicObject = new ExpandoObject();
    var properties = value.GetType().GetProperties(
        BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
    {
        if (propertyInfo.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
        {
            var propertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(value);
            dynamicObject[propertyInfo.Name] = propertyValue;
        }
    }

    return dynamicObject;
}
```

Usage:

```
var room = new Room();
room.NumberOfDoors = 3;

dynamic dynamicObject = ConvertToDynamic(room);
dynamicObject.WhateverYouWant = 7;
```

Now `dynamicObject.NumberOfDoors` will be 3, and `dynamicObject.WhateverYouWant` will be 7.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. Please see the updates to find the context why I need to inject a property in the concrete class object.

Comment: @Annie I have included some extra detail.  I hope it helps.